create a channel in my Hyperledger Fabric network using the Raft consensus mechanism
Problem:
I am trying to create a channel in my Hyperledger Fabric network using the Raft consensus mechanism. The orderer service has TLS enabled, but I’m encountering a certificate validation failure during the channel creation process.
Error message:
Error: got unexpected status: BAD_REQUEST -- consensus metadata update for channel creation is invalid: invalid new config metadata: consenter orderer0-org0:7048 has invalid certificate: verifying tls client cert with serial number 453825717574771841881597218695895193507241958748: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
Channel creation command:
export CHANNEL_NAME=mychannel
export ORDERER_CA=/Users/berich/Desktop/go/project_fabric/fabric-ca/orderer-tls-client-certfiles/orderertls/orderer1/msp/tlscacerts/tls-0-0-0-0-7056.pem
export CORE_PEER_ID=peer0.org1
export CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org1:7051
export CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=org1MSP
export CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/Users/berich/Desktop/go/project_fabric/fabric-ca/org1/admin/msp

peer channel create -o orderer1-org0:7050 -c ${CHANNEL_NAME} --ordererTLSHostnameOverride orderer1-org0 -f ../configx/channel-artifacts/${CHANNEL_NAME}.tx --outputBlock ../configx/channel-artifacts/${CHANNEL_NAME}.block --tls --cafile ${ORDERER_CA}


Orderer configuration:
export ORDERER_HOST=orderer1-org0
export ORDERER_GENERAL_LISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0
export ORDERER_GENERAL_LISTENPORT=7050
export ORDERER_GENERAL_GENESISMETHOD=file
export ORDERER_GENERAL_GENESISFILE=/Users/berich/Desktop/go/project_fabric/fabric/configx/channel-artifacts/genesis.block
export ORDERER_GENERAL_LOCALMSPID=org0MSP
export ORDERER_GENERAL_LOCALMSPDIR=/Users/berich/Desktop/go/project_fabric/fabric-ca/org0ca/org0/orderer/msp
export ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_ENABLED=true
export ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_PRIVATEKEY=/Users/berich/Desktop/go/project_fabric/fabric-ca/orderer-tls-client-certfiles/orderertls/orderer1/msp/keystore/1611a999198ec8f5f039e0540e9c9a79db384f260b62c905acd7388a2dc48ff9_sk
export ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_CERTIFICATE=/Users/berich/Desktop/go/project_fabric/fabric-ca/orderer-tls-client-certfiles/orderertls/orderer1/msp/signcerts/cert.pem
export ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_ROOTCAS=/Users/berich/Desktop/go/project_fabric/fabric-ca/orderer-tls-client-certfiles/orderertls/orderer1/msp/tlscacerts/tls-0-0-0-0-7056.pem
export ORDERER_GENERAL_CLUSTER_CLIENTCERTIFICATE=/Users/berich/Desktop/go/project_fabric/fabric-ca/orderer-tls-client-certfiles/orderertls/orderer1/msp/signcerts/cert.pem
export ORDERER_GENERAL_CLUSTER_CLIENTPRIVATEKEY=/Users/berich/Desktop/go/project_fabric/fabric-ca/orderer-tls-client-certfiles/orderertls/orderer1/msp/keystore/1611a999198ec8f5f039e0540e9c9a79db384f260b62c905acd7388a2dc48ff9_sk
export ORDERER_GENERAL_CLUSTER_ROOTCAS=/Users/berich/Desktop/go/project_fabric/fabric-ca/orderer-tls-client-certfiles/orderertls/orderer1/msp/tlscacerts/tls-0-0-0-0-7056.pem
export FABRIC_CFG_PATH=/Users/berich/Desktop/go/project_fabric/fabric/config/orderer1
orderer


configtx.yaml
Profiles:
  TwoOrgsOrdererGenesis:
    <<: *ChannelDefaults
    Orderer:
      <<: *OrdererDefaults
      OrdererType: etcdraft  # 使用 Raft 共识算法
      EtcdRaft:
        Consenters:
          - Host: orderer0-org0  # 第一个共识节点
            Port: 7048
            ClientTLSCert: /Users/berich/Desktop/go/project_fabric/fabric-ca/orderer-tls-client-certfiles/orderertls/orderer0/msp/signcerts/cert.pem
            ServerTLSCert: /Users/berich/Desktop/go/project_fabric/fabric-ca/orderer-tls-client-certfiles/orderertls/orderer0/msp/signcerts/cert.pem
          - Host: orderer1-org0  # 第二个共识节点
            Port: 7050
            ClientTLSCert: /Users/berich/Desktop/go/project_fabric/fabric-ca/orderer-tls-client-certfiles/orderertls/orderer1/msp/signcerts/cert.pem
            ServerTLSCert: /Users/berich/Desktop/go/project_fabric/fabric-ca/orderer-tls-client-certfiles/orderertls/orderer1/msp/signcerts/cert.pem
          - Host: orderer2-org0  # 第三个共识节点
            Port: 7049
            ClientTLSCert: /Users/berich/Desktop/go/project_fabric/fabric-ca/orderer-tls-client-certfiles/orderertls/orderer2/msp/signcerts/cert.pem
            ServerTLSCert: /Users/berich/Desktop/go/project_fabric/fabric-ca/orderer-tls-client-certfiles/orderertls/orderer2/msp/signcerts/cert.pem
      Addresses:  # Orderer 节点的地址列表
        - orderer0-org0:7048
        - orderer1-org0:7050
        - orderer2.org0:7049
      Organizations:
        - *org0
      Capabilities: *OrdererCapabilities
    Application:
      <<: *ApplicationDefaults
      Organizations:
        - *org1
      Capabilities: *ApplicationCapabilities
    Consortiums:
      SampleConsortium:
        Organizations:
          - *org1
          - *org0
  TwoOrgsChannel:
    Consortium: SampleConsortium
    <<: *ChannelDefaults
    Application:
      <<: *ApplicationDefaults
      Organizations:
        - *org1
      Capabilities:
        <<: *ApplicationCapabilities

Issue:
During the channel creation, I receive the error indicating that the certificate for orderer1-org0:7050 is invalid due to it being signed by an unknown authority.
The orderer service is correctly configured with TLS certificates and keys.
The ORDERER_CA environment variable is pointing to the correct CA root certificate file.
I'm unsure if there's a conflict between the certificates for orderer0-org0 and orderer1-org0.
What I’ve Tried:
Verified that the ORDERER_CA points to the correct CA root certificate.
Checked the TLS certificate validity for both orderer0-org0:7048 and orderer1-org0:7050.
Reviewed the orderer service's TLS and cluster certificate configuration, but the issue persists.
My Questions:
How can I ensure that the orderer service is using the correct certificate so that it passes verification during the channel creation process?
Are there any specific details I should be aware of regarding TLS certificate and cluster configuration for orderers when using the Raft consensus mechanism?
What could be causing the "certificate signed by unknown authority" error even though the CA certificate seems to be configured correctly?
